# Getting a set of values from a dictionary of sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

What is the preferred method to get the set of values from a dictionary of sets?

I came up with using `reduce` and `itervalues()` was wondering if there is a better method.

```
>>> m_dict = { 'a': set([1,2]),
... 'b': set([1,4,5]),
... 'c': set([2,8,9]) }
>>> print m_dict
{'a': set([1, 2]), 'c': set([8, 9, 2]), 'b': set([1, 4, 5])}
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x.union(y), m_dict.itervalues())
set([1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9])
>>>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set.union` can accept multiple sets so, `set.union(*m_dict.values())`

Comment: Strangely I spent part of today doing thought exercises trying to think of uses for reduce...

Comment: I absolutely adore Python's value packing/unpacking!

Comment: @DTing: :D I like that name for it! "Splat"! That's sort of what it does, after all.

Comment: I'd be interested in the history behind the splat naming, I [read somewhere](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/splat) it was due to the "squashed-bug" appearance of the asterisk on many early line printers.